# Starting text right after section or subsection title

Tags: sectioning

Is it possible to start your text right after the section or subsection title (without starting a new line)? Thank you. I hope the question is clear enough and does not need a MWE.

Comment: It is _always_ best to provide a MWE as it maximises the chance that (a) you supply enough information and that (b) the person answering tests their answer. In this case the answer probably depends on which class you are using, but you haven't said.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

David has already provided the package-free solution; here's another option, using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package (simply selecting the `runin` predefined format):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section} 
Test
\subsection{Test Subsection} 
Test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

In the default classes the run-in style is used for `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` to change `\section` to use the same find it's defintion, in `article` it is

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

and you need to invert the sign of the 3/4th arguments as that is used as a switch to specify run-in style so

```
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {3.5ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                   {-1em}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

Also changed the 4th arg to specify 1em space after (rather than below) the heading, as for `\paragraph`