# Starting text right after section in -res- class

Tags: sectioning, titles, cv, sections-paragraphs, resume

Is it possible to start your text right after the section in the res class?
As an alternative, one could also fake a section title's look (font) etc. However, how would you fully indent it to the left then (in res class the titles are further on the left than the text)?

Thanks!

This question has been answered already [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99170/starting-text-right-after-section-or-subsection-title). However, not for the res document class.

```
\documentclass{res}

\begin{document}
\begin{resume}

%Section
\section{TEST:} test 

%Alternative
\vspace{\parskip}
\large{TEST:} test

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Thanks @ Werner for the first solution: Do you also have tip for making it work with  \newsectionwidth{10pt}? The given solution breaks down when you introduce the new section width.

```
\documentclass{res}

\newsectionwidth{10pt} %So the text is not indented too much under section headings

\begin{document}
\begin{resume}

%Section
\section{TEST:} test 

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\leavevmode{\llap{\sectionfont #1\ }}\ignorespaces}

%Section
\section{TEST:} test

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would steer clear from the [`res` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/res) as its deprecated/really old. You're better off setting it in the `article` document class, or using something like [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv).

You can redefine `\section` to be

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\leavevmode{\llap{\sectionfont #1\ }}\ignorespaces}
```

This just inserts the section using a `l`eft over`l`ap into the left margin.

[image]

```
\documentclass{res}

\begin{document}
\begin{resume}

%Section
\section{TEST:} test 

\bigskip

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\leavevmode{\llap{\sectionfont #1\ }}\ignorespaces}

%Section
\section{TEST:} test

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Werner. I agree that -res- isn't the most convenient. But I do not have time to change it all around right now.

Comment: Do you also have tip for making it work with \newsectionwidth{10pt}? Thanks!

Comment: @Max: You can adjust the redefinition of `\section` to insert whatever space you want. For example, try `\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\leavevmode\hspace*{\sectionwidth}\llap{\sectionfont #1\ }\ignorespaces}` or something more rigid like `50pt` instead of `\sectionwidth`.