# How to have Run-in Section in a separate command?

Tags: sectioning

In the question asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99170/starting-text-right-after-section-or-subsection-title), How to have the same solution but in a different command without affecting the `\section` command? I mean I would like to create another command e.g. `\runinsection` that would make the text continue beside the section header while maintaining the `\section` command with its normal behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although this is your second question, nobody has welcomed you here yet... So, [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what can be the use for this.

Comment: In my case it was a one line section that caused me to go into a new page having also only one line, it's a 3 page document, the document did not look nice

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply define a new command `\runinsection`

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\runinsection{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {3.5ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                   {-1em}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother
```

and use it as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\runinsection{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {3.5ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                   {-1em}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum} %just for the example

\begin{document}

\section{This is a normal section}

\lipsum[1]

\runinsection{This is a run-in section}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: @MysticOdin You're welcome.