# Header in first line of section, not line above

Tags: positioning

I'm trying to put the section/subsection header in the first line of a section instead of in the line above a section.

Instead of:

> **1 Header**
>
> Body of section.

I want

> **1 Header** Body of section.

[image: Like this]

Comment: can you please be more specific? this is very vague.

Comment: Hi @DIWesser: This has been asked before [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42943/no-newline-after-subsection).

Comment: @naphanneal I've added a couple examples.

Comment: @Jeffery Shivers That does look like exactly what I want. My only issue is it removes the numbers. Any idea how I would preserve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is adapted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99170/starting-text-right-after-section-or-subsection-title):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[runin]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\section{my section}
Section context.
\section{my other section}
More section content
\end{document}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.